# "select like" find line of text

Tags: mysql, select, text, sql-like

Searching in a text field that contains a list I want to select all records that contain the search string as a line of text.
So

```
"SELECT ID FROM 'titles' WHERE keywords LIKE '%easter rising%'
```

should only find records that contain either exactly this string or any number of lines of text before and/or after it, but not those containing both words as single lines and not those containing e.g. "easter egg rising" instead.

```
ID       keywords
1         ireland
          history
          easter rising

2         britain
          easter rising campaign

3         france
          easter
          rising

4         easter rising
```

In this example I would want to find 1 and 4

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - [why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder & sorry for the omission, I hope it is better this way.

Comment: If you use `,` as separator instead of line breaks you could use `FIND_IN_SET()`. But I'd rather normalize the schema.

Comment: Paul, absolutely, the whole idea of the operation is to get the data into a form that allows for normalization, after I'm done with the operation the field containing the list will be deleted and be replaced by a a table.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution now but I'm not sure this will work in other environments but the somewhat special way SQL is used in FileMaker. Here I can use a construct like

```
  SELECT id 
  FROM titles
  WHERE '¶' + keywords + '¶'  LIKE '%¶easter rising¶%'
```

The ¶ represents a line break here